# pyspark row wise condition on spark dataframe with 1000 columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe (df) having n rows and m columns and two Python lists (lowerL and upperL) each having m values. I want to sample all rows which lie in between lowerL and upperL. And then take sum of df.col_1000 (col_1000 is one of the column of df) from the sampled dataframe.
I am using PySpark (Spark 1.6.1).

For n=5 and m=4:

**df** looks like:

```
|col_1|col_2|col_3|Result|

+-----+-----+-----+------+

|62.45| 41.2|62.49|   1.0|

|56.45|46.39|60.38|   1.0|

|68.37|43.56|71.97|   0.0|

| 53.9| 51.7|70.12|   1.0|

| 56.4|57.32|48.39|   0.0|

+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

**lowerL** looks like:

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+

|col_1|col_2|col_3|Result|

+-----+-----+-----+------+

|51.81|42.22|51.48|  -1.0|

+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

**upperL** looks like:

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+

|col_1|col_2|col_3|Result|

+-----+-----+-----+------+

|61.91|58.63|72.48|   2.0|

+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

**Result I want should be:**

```
|col_1|col_2|col_3|Result|

+-----+-----+-----+------+

|56.45|46.39|60.38|   1.0|

| 53.9| 51.7|70.12|   1.0|

+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

Comment: any sample? This line is confusing ``I want to sample all rows which lie in between lowerL and upperL``

Comment: I have edited the question with a sample example. In the example, 2 rows out of 5 rows of df lie in between lowerL and upperL.

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample example:-

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([ [62.45, 41.2, 62.49, 1.0], [56.45, 46.39, 60.38, 1.0], [68.37, 43.56, 71.97, 0.0], [ 53.9, 51.7, 70.12, 1.0], [ 56.4, 57.32, 48.39, 0.0]], ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'Result'])
df.show()

+-----+-----+-----+------+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|Result|
+-----+-----+-----+------+
|62.45| 41.2|62.49|   1.0|
|56.45|46.39|60.38|   1.0|
|68.37|43.56|71.97|   0.0|
| 53.9| 51.7|70.12|   1.0|
| 56.4|57.32|48.39|   0.0|
+-----+-----+-----+------+

lower_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[51.81, 42.22, 51.48, -1.0]], ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'Result'])
lower_df.show()

+-----+-----+-----+------+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|Result|
+-----+-----+-----+------+
|51.81|42.22|51.48|  -1.0|
+-----+-----+-----+------+


upper_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[61.91, 58.63, 72.48, 2.0]], ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'Result'])
upper_df.show()

+-----+-----+-----+------+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|Result|
+-----+-----+-----+------+
|61.91|58.63|72.48|   2.0|
+-----+-----+-----+------+

lower_df_val = lower_df.first()
upper_df_val = upper_df.first()

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

for fil in [(F.col(df_column) > F.lit(lower_df_val[df_column])) & (F.col(df_column) < F.lit(upper_df_val[df_column]))  for df_column in df.columns]:
    df = df.filter(fil)

df.show()    


+-----+-----+-----+------+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|Result|
+-----+-----+-----+------+
|56.45|46.39|60.38|   1.0|
| 53.9| 51.7|70.12|   1.0|
+-----+-----+-----+------+
```